# Integrating Docusign in our webapp

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to Docusign and we have a requirement to integrate Docusign in our web app. I have gone through all the links for integrating docusign into a web app using REST Api calls. After thorough read and watching youtube videos, I came to know that we can integrate docusign in our web app through REST API calls but for the same additionally we need to develop our own UI to upload documents and send it to the recipient. But basically we are looking something where we can be reidrected to docusign from our webapp to perform all the operations of sending document for signing and once document is sent then I will be redirected back to our web app.

Kindly help with the above query and let me know if my understanding is correct for integration of docusign and for the same developing our own UI in our web app. Also please let me know if there is any alternative to fullfill the requirement of directly accessing docusign from our web app and performing all required operations of sending a document to recipient.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you want a button on your web app that says "Sign with DocuSign" and then what?

Most customers who want to send from their web app already have the documents controlled by their web app.

They:

- authenticate the user with DocuSign (OAuth Authorization Code Grant)
- Upload the document to DocuSign from their app.
- Add tabs (signing fields) to the documents programmatically. (This is not hard and it saves the sender a lot of work.)
- Upload the recipients (signers, copy-only recipients, etc)
- And then tell DocuSign to send the envelope (the transaction).
- Applications can also monitor the progress of the envelope through the signing process and programatically act on the signed documents.

The above is not hard to do and provides a good user experience.

You can also redirect the user of your application to DocuSign to accomplish any/all of the above manually. But the more the user does manually, the less convenient the integration will be for them.

If you want the manual experience, check out the [EnvelopeViews::createSender method](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender).

Comment: Thanks Larry. The solution provided above will redirect to an envelope which is in completed state (sent). But I am looking for something where a user will be redirected to docusign page from where the user will be able to create a new envelope, add documents, add recipients and send it to the recipients. Thanks

Comment: You can create the envelope in a draft state (see the `status` element), then redirect the user (the sender) to the createSender view. They will see the partially completed envelope and can then add additional information/recipients/documents to the envelope before sending it.